# On click of update i want to navigate to update employees in angular what am i missing?

Tags: angular, angular7-router

I have added routing in app-routing.module.ts
I have configured path employees/:id in routing file
and in employee.ts i have written a function to navigate to update employees component but it is not happening.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',component:EmployeesComponent},
  { path: 'employees',component:EmployeesComponent},
  { path: 'employees/:id',component:UpdateEmployeeComponent}
];
```

And I have written a function in employee.component.ts

```
updateEmployee(id){
    console.log(`Update Employee ${id}`);
    this.router.navigate(['employees/', id]);
  }
```

But I'm unable to navigate to update employee component. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 updateEmployee(id){
    console.log(`Update Employee ${id}`);
    this.router.navigate(['employees', id]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your html file. And use

`this.router.navigate(['employee', id]);`
for relative path or

`this.router.navigateByUrl('/employee/' + id);`
for absolute path